# JCo IDoc server cannot receive messages due to port issue

Tags: java, jco, idoc, sapjco3

I have a java based IDoc listening server which is built using JCo 3. When I started it and sent a IDoc from the sap system it gives me an exception in below trace.

As it says, I thought this is due to unavailability of message server and logged in to SAP machine and using `netstat` checked the opened ports.

Port 3600 was not listening but port 7200 is reported to be opened by `msg_server.exe`. I have set my JCo server side machine's `/etc/services` file to `sapmsNSP   3600/tcp` but even if I changed it to 7200 it gives me exception saying internal error.

Trace:

> ```
>    com.sap.conn.idoc.IDocRuntimeException: Failed to resolve repository reference @MYDESTINATION
>       at com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.rt.DefaultJCoIDocServer$IDocRepositoryMapBox$IDocRepositoryReference.getRepository(DefaultJCoIDocServer.java:245)
>       at com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.rt.DefaultJCoIDocServer$IDocRepositoryMapBox.getRepository(DefaultJCoIDocServer.java:397)
>       at com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.rt.DefaultJCoIDocServer.getIDocRepository(DefaultJCoIDocServer.java:128)
>       at com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.rt.DefaultJCoIDocServerWorker$IDocDispatcher.createIDocDocumentListArray(DefaultJCoIDocServerWorker.java:445)
>       at com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.rt.DefaultJCoIDocServerWorker$IDocDispatcher.handleRequest(DefaultJCoIDocServerWorker.java:209)
>       at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServerWorker.dispatchRequest(DefaultServerWorker.java:148)
>       at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.MiddlewareJavaRfc$JavaRfcServer.dispatchRequest(MiddlewareJavaRfc.java:3680)
>       at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.MiddlewareJavaRfc$JavaRfcServer.executePlayback(MiddlewareJavaRfc.java:3158)
>       at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.MiddlewareJavaRfc$JavaRfcServer.playbackTRfc(MiddlewareJavaRfc.java:2981)
>       at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.MiddlewareJavaRfc$JavaRfcServer.handletRfcRequest(MiddlewareJavaRfc.java:2875)
>       at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.MiddlewareJavaRfc$JavaRfcServer.listen(MiddlewareJavaRfc.java:2674)
>       at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServerWorker.dispatch(DefaultServerWorker.java:275)
>       at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServerWorker.loop(DefaultServerWorker.java:356)
>       at com.sap.conn.jco.rt.DefaultServerWorker.run(DefaultServerWorker.java:232)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>    Caused by: com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException: (102) JCO_ERROR_COMMUNICATION: Connect to message server host failed
>    Connection parameters: TYPE=B DEST=MYDESTINATION MSHOST=192.168.56.101 R3NAME=NSP GROUP=PUBLIC PCS=1
>    
>    ERROR       partner '192.168.56.101:sapmsNSP' not reached
>    TIME        Thu Jan 12 16:19:21 2017
>    RELEASE     721
>    COMPONENT   NI (network interface)
>    VERSION     40
>    RC          -10
>    MODULE      nixxi.cpp
>    LINE        3283
>    DETAIL      NiPConnect2: 192.168.56.101:3600
>    SYSTEM CALL connect
>    ERRNO       61
>    ERRNO TEXT  Connection refused
>    COUNTER     1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that no running process on host 192.168.56.101 listens to the port 3600. This means that either the SAP message server process is listening to a different port or it is simply not running at all.

If you can do a group logon with an SAP GUI to the ABAP system NSP, your services file should be configured correctly. By the way, the SAP message server process is usually named msg_server.exe on Windows - not message_server.exe. If you changed your services file you should at least get a different error message at the DETAIL error message part showing the modified port number. Otherwise you failed to change the services file (not saved? no carriage return after the last line?) or you did not restart your JCo server program after changing the services file.

Comment: edited: should be 'msg_server.exe'. My services file is fine. How ever I could solve this issue by adding r ```rdisp/msserv = 3``` to  C:\usr\sap\NSP\SYS\profile\NSP_XXXXXX00_hostnam file. I'm not sure why.

Comment: `rdisp/msserv` specifies the message server service name at SAP system side. IMHO it should be set to the value `sapmsNSP`. I have doubts that your change has something to do with the previous error message. Maybe the value '3' is ignored and some default is used instead which results in using port 3600 now. Please check which port is configured for `sapmsNSP` in the services file on the SAP system host(s).